# WCF on Win Server 2008 and IIS7 with only net.tcp binding hide IIS features

Tags: wcf, iis-7, windows-server-2008, nettcpbinding, net-tcp

I've installed HTTP Activation and Non-HTTP Activation IIS's features for Framework.NET 3.0 under WCF Activation feature.

I'm trying to remove http and https bindings (under default Web Site) from IIS Manager and leave others (net.tcp, net.msmq, etc.) but if I close and re-open IIS manager I not found any icons in the right panel (Feature View). The only feature I see is IIS Manager Permissions.

It's right I don't see them?

I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you only use non HTTP activation, you don't need IIS Manager any more. IIS Manager is designed for HTTP web sites and FTP sites.